# single-row subquery returns more than one row on date columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a code that is given this problem in Oracle :  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"  When I used only inline code  code it was working

I have tried only the inline code below which is working fine

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(theDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 
   NORWEGIAN'),
       'DD/MM/YYYY') 
       from mastertable
```

But the combination of code is not working by combining two select statement

```
   SELECT  aircraft
    , country
     ,   (select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(theDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE 
  = NORWEGIAN'),
       'DD/MM/YYYY') 
       from mastertable )

        FROM mastertable

   FULL OUTER JOIN continent ON mastertable.id = continent.id
```

Comment: Error says it all.  Your subquery is returning more than one row.  Does it return more than one row when run by itself?

Comment: Yes, But am new to Oracle what can I do

Comment: If I run this line alone it works : select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(theDATE,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE 
  = NORWEGIAN'),
       'DD/MM/YYYY') 
       from mastertable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your subquery restrict to only one ID as

```
SELECT aircraft,
       country,
       (SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(theDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI',
                               'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = NORWEGIAN'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
          FROM mastertable
         WHERE id = m.id)
  FROM mastertable m
  FULL JOIN continent c
    ON m.id = c.id
```

presuming ID is a primary key column.

Comment: Thanks. I just put where in it for the ID unique in both tables

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply

```
SELECT m.aircraft,
       c.country,
       to_char(to_date(m.thedate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi', 'nls_date_language = norwegian'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') the_date
FROM mastertable m full outer join continent c on m.id = c.id;
```

I mean, what is the purpose of the query you're trying to (ab)use?

Also, what is `THEDATE`'s datatype? Looks like a `VARCHAR2`; is it? What good does `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` do here? All you deal with are *digits* (there are no month or day *names*) so that could be simplified to

```
to_char(to_date(m.thedate, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi'), 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: I need to use it because the SQL developer hide the time and I have to change the settings in the Preference to the format 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi' and the language is Norwegian. I have tried that already and is not working. I will check tomorrow and see what it will give. I used thedate because I change the column name, ignore the column name for now

Comment: OK, but - what difference does it make? Now is `07.02.2019 21:41` and it looks the same in Norvegian, English, Croatian ... no difference. The fact that you don't see time component in SQL Developer doesn't matter. Besides, you didn't say what is THEDATE's datatype - possible solution might depend on that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but am writing the code to export it to excel and the requirement is that I should have date column separate and time column separate. That is why I enable the time in preference.   I will still write TO_DATE function for time as well. The thedate datatype is date field

Comment: If THEDATE is DATE (datatype), then you'd split date and time as `to_char(thedate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') the_date, to_char(thedate, 'hh24:mi') the_time`. As simple as that

Comment: I will  update you all tomorrow. Thanks for your time

Comment: OK, no problem. Sleep well.